# Removing trusted Phone number

Tags: ios

My phone number inadvertently got added as a trusted phone number for someone else's iPad.

The issue is that there isnt another number to use in its place.

So a couple of question in here, is it possible to just remove the trusted number and if not, is there a way to ensure the 2FA uses trusted devices rather than the trusted number for verification purposes?

Answer (score 2):

From Apple KB - [Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/HT204915)

> You can update your trusted phone numbers by following these steps:
>
> Go to your [Apple ID account page](https://appleid.apple.com/).
> Sign in with your Apple ID.
> Go
> to the Security section and click Edit.
>
> If you want to add a phone number, click Add a Trusted Phone Number
> and enter the phone number. Choose to verify the number with a text
> message or an automated phone call, and click Continue. To remove a
> trusted phone number, click x icon next to the phone number you want
> to remove.

Presumably, if this is someone else's iPad, they will have to do the removal.
Alternatively, you may be able to see & remove their device from the Devices list on your Apple ID page. I'm not sure how this would affect future trust, as it wouldn't necessarily clear the number from their account.

Comment: It doesn't allow us to remove the number because its the only number. This would work if there was multiple numbers, but this isnt the case here.

Comment: Then you'll have to persuade them to put their own number in, or see if my second suggestion works.